# Simpel php form not working

Tags: php, xampp

I'm struggling in a advanced php form in a project. I thought "let begin with the basic". So I made just an easy php form. Looks like this even doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**producten.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>producten</title>
    <form action="formtest.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" size="25" name="name" >
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**formtest.php**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this locally? And the form is inside the head, not the body where it should be (although that's not the issue in itself, its just invalid HTML markup).

Comment: running as `http://localhost` or `file:///`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://localhost

Comment: are all services running and a green light?

Answer (score 3):

You have your form in your `<head>`  tag, it should be in the `<body>`

I updated your code for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>producten</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="formtest.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" size="25" name="name" >
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: changed it, doesn't do it

Comment: Are you running your site on a local webserver like usbWebserver or XAMPP or WAMPP?

Comment: While the HTML markup is invalid, it would still work. @Martijn

Comment: Yes i'm running on XAMPP

Comment: @Qirel I've never heard of html code in the `<head>` actually displaying and working.... I guess I've learnt something new today aswell

Comment: @user5488652 are there any errors? because I'm prety sure it should work

Comment: Does the problem have something to do with the fact I'm using XAMPP?

Comment: XAMPP is a good webserver to use, Im going to check if I get it to work myself locally

Comment: @user5488652 See [this comment by Fred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492607/simpel-php-form-not-working/43492673?noredirect=1#comment74039991_43492607), I'm guessing that's where you've gone wrong. Also you'll need to make sure that Apache is actually running without errors, check your XAMPP Control Panel.

Comment: It works for me. I am using WAMPP, so I guess it's something with XAMPP. Try using a different webserver or check if PHP is installed and configurated properly.

Comment: this has nothing to do with XAMPP. Its probably the way OP configured APACHE

Comment: @Akin what you mean by OP?

Comment: OP means "original poster" or something. so You, @user5488652 are OP